# Extracting a word from string from n rows and append that word as a new col in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I have got a data set that contains 3 columns and has 15565 observations. one of the columns has got several words in the same row.

What I am looking to do is to extract a particular word from each row and append it to a new column (i will have 4 cols in total)

The problem is that the word that i am looking for are not the same and they are not always on the same position.

Here is an extract of my DS:

```
  x    y    z
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  1    T    3C00652722 (T558799A)
  2    T    NA >> MSP: T0578836A & 3C03024632
  3    T    T0579010A, 3C03051500, EAET03051496
  4    U    T0023231A > MSP: T0577506A & 3C02808556
  8    U    (T561041A C72/59460)>POPMigr.T576447A,C72/221816*3C00721502
```

I am looking to extract all the words that start with `3C`and are 10 characters long and then append the to a new col so it looks like this:

```
  x    y    z                                         Ref    
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
  1    T    3C00652722 (T558799A)                     3C00652722 
  2    T    NA >> MSP: T0578836A & 3C03024632         3C03024632
  3    T    T0579010A, 3C03051500, EAET03051496       3C03051500
  4    U    T0023231A > MSP: T0577506A & 3C02808556   3C02808556
  8    U    >POPMigr.T576447A,C72/221816*3C00721502   3C00721502
```

I have tried using the `Contains`, `Like` and `substring` methods but it does not give me the results i am looking for as it basically finds the rows that have the 3C number but does not extract it, it just copies the whole cell and pastes is on the `Ref` column.

Comment: share your attempt to give us a starting point and something to correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, SQL Server does not have a native regex extract string function, which is probably the best tool for this job.  You could look into a custom UDF for regex if you want.

Comment: Have you tried CHARINDEX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have good string functions, but this should suffice if you only want to extract one value per row:

```
select t.*,
       left(stuff(col,
                  1,
                  patindex('%3C[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', col),
                  ''
                 ), 10)
from t ;
```

Comment: This is NOT the first time you have helped me! you are a true Jedi Master!